# writing '\t' '\n' etc. characters in a file like a string_?

Tags: java, character

hi there i am trying to write a code that generates automatically code and writes in a file.so the problem is when i try to write '\t' '\n' etc. characters i am facing with problems.

```
    FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("...\\PersonalList.java");
    PrintStream pr2 = new PrintStream(fos2);

    for (Iterator<String> itr = name.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {

        i++;

        s_str =  itr.next();

        if(i==counter)
            pr2.print('"' + s_str.toUpperCase() + '"' + ");\n");

        else 
            pr2.print('"' + s_str.toUpperCase() + '\t' + '"'  + '+'); 

    }
```

and my goal is writing a code  for example "pr.println("var1\t" + "var2\t") into another file and when i compile that file it would create a text file, so when i look at my .txt file i should see "NAME (here must be white space character)   LAST_NAME". but in '\t' character it writes
pr.println("var1"   +    "var2"). i hope i explain my work correctly. : ) and i appreciated if you could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean, but I *suspect* you're just trying to escape the backslash:

```
 pr2.print('"' + s_str.toUpperCase() + "\\t\"+");
```

(I've taken the liberty of combining all the characters you've got at the end into a single string, which means we need to escape the double quote as well, hence the `\"`.)

Comment: yesss. it worked. could you explain me that how it works please : )

Comment: @user743898: `\t` is the escape sequence for "tab" but `\\` is the escape sequence for "backslash". So there's a backslash followed by a t, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character is a special character used to escape things like tabs (`\t`), newlines (`\n`), etc. So if you want to print a backslash, you have to type `\\`.

In your particular case, you want to print out `"\\t"`.